# Problem calling a SOAP WCF service (.NET 4.5.2) from .NET Core in Server 2008 R2

Tags: asp.net-core, wcf, asp.net-core-webapi, windows-server-2008-r2

I have made a Web API service in .NET Core (I've tried both 2.2 and 3.1).

It is a bridge to an old WCF SOAP service (.NET 4.5.2) and it runs fine when both services are on my Windows 10 development machine.

When the WCF service is placed on our Windows Server 2008 R2 server, I get this error:

> "message": "The content type text/html; charset=UTF-8 of the response message does not match the content type of the binding (text/xml; charset=utf-8). If using a custom encoder, be sure that the IsContentTypeSupported method is implemented properly. The first 1024 bytes of the response were: '<HTML lang="en"><link rel="alternate" type="text/xml" href="http://testxxxitms-api.xxxbilling.org/Service.svc?***disco***"

The error is that I get an HTML answer instead of XML and it seems that the reason is that the call is somehow changed to a 'disco' call. The only thing I change in the client, is the endpoint address and it does not contain the disco parameter.

I can call the WCF service with a SOAP UI.

I have these references to System.ServiceModel-** assemblies.

```
<PackageReference Include="System.Private.ServiceModel" Version="4.7.0" />    
<PackageReference Include="System.ServiceModel.Duplex" Version="4.7.0" />    
<PackageReference Include="System.ServiceModel.Http" Version="4.7.0" />    
<PackageReference Include="System.ServiceModel.NetTcp" Version="4.7.0" />    
<PackageReference Include="System.ServiceModel.Primitives" Version="4.7.0" />
<PackageReference Include="System.ServiceModel.Security" Version="4.7.0" />
```

What can cause this behaviour?

Comment: How did you call the WCF service in WebApi project, client proxy or directly seeding an http request via an Http class library? When the server changes to Server2008R2, I think we'd better add the service reference in WebAPI to generate the client proxy object to call the service.

Comment: Hi Abraham. 

I have tried generating a connected service 《wcf ) in vs2019, svcutil from .net 4 and dotnet_svcutil.

/Jesper

Comment: I almost forget you are using an AspnetCore-based WebAPI project, this might be incompatible with the WCF service.  I recommend that you call the service once in your Core-based console project to test whether CoreSDK is compatible with the current WCF service. This is done by creating a core-based console program and then adding a service reference to generate the client proxy. The proxy class is then used to invoke the service. Notice that we need to modify the default service address in reference.cs.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/additional-tools/wcf-web-service-reference-guide

Answer (score 1):

Abraham Qian's input in the comments led me to try a myriad of solutions.
My conclusion is that it will not work on Windows Server 2008.

I have insisted to have the server upgraded to Windows Server 2012 and now it works.